# Ideals of Polynomial Rings and Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $F \subseteq K$ be fields, and suppose $f_1, ... , f_t \in F[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  Let $R = F[X_1, ... , X_n]$, and let $S = K[X_1, ... , X_n]$.  Is it always true that $(f_1S + \cdots + f_t S) \cap R = f_1R + \cdots + f_t R$?

This seems like a natural thing to conclude, and I think I can prove this in the case $t = 1$, but I also know that intersections don't always distribute over sums.

Comment: The first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83731/extension-and-contraction-of-ideals-in-polynomial-rings) appears to answer your question in the affirmative (though that answer has a downvote and I have not checked it).

Comment: Dear Julian,  I have checked the answer you refer to and it is absolutely correct and very well written. The same goes for the alternative answer given by Makoto.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true.

The ring extension $R = F[X_1, ... , X_n]\subset S = K[X_1, ... , X_n]$ has the property that $S$ is a free $R$-module (since $K$ is a free $F$-module). This shows that it is faithfully flat, and we are done.

Comment: Sorry, but what's faithful flatness got to do with anything?