# Question in a proof from Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry: Hilbert’s Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying chapter 1 of Gathmann's notes about algebraic geometry and there is something that I don't understand in the proof of proposition 1.2.4, where Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is proved for $\mathbb{C}$. The part that I don't understand is as follows.

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. Since $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ is Noetherian, we may assume that $\mathfrak{m}=(f_1,\cdots,f_r)$, where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. Let K be the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ obtained by adjointing to $\mathbb{Q}$ all coefficients of the $f_i$. Let $\mathfrak{m}_{0}=\mathfrak{m} \cap K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. Note that then $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}_{0} \cdot \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$.

Next we are going to prove that $\mathfrak{m}_{0}$ is a maximal ideal of $K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. Suppose not, then let $\mathfrak{m}_{0} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}_{0}^{\prime} \subsetneq K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$.  Let $\mathfrak{m}^{\prime}=\mathfrak{m}_{0}^{\prime} \cdot \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. The author then induces a contradiction $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}^{\prime} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ by multiplying $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$ on $\mathfrak{m}_{0} \subsetneq \mathfrak{m}_{0}^{\prime} \subsetneq K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$, which I don't understand.

I can prove $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq   \mathfrak{m}^{\prime}$ by the following way:

It can be verified that $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq   \mathfrak{m}^{\prime}$, so it remains to be proved that $\mathfrak{m} \neq   \mathfrak{m}^{\prime}$. Suppose not, then $\mathfrak{m} =   \mathfrak{m}^{\prime}$. Let $g \in \mathfrak{m}_{0}^{\prime} - \mathfrak{m}_{0}$, by definition $g \in \mathfrak{m}^{\prime}=\mathfrak{m}$ and $g \in K[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$, so $g \in \mathfrak{m}_{0}$ and we obtain a contradiction.

But the same method becomes invalid when I try to prove $ \mathfrak{m}^{\prime} \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]$. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Referring to a linked image is not a great way to bring in outside content - people don't click links much, and images are neither searchable nor accessible. Please consider typing up the relevant portions of the proof in your post using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have typed the relevant portions of the proof and what I have tried to figure out the problem. Any help?

Comment: The key claim is that the contraction of the extension is the original ideal. Luckily this is covered on MSE already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83731/extension-and-contraction-of-ideals-in-polynomial-rings) - does this answer your question?

Comment: I think so. Thanks so much!