Contraction of Ideals & their Reconstructibility
Let $R^d :=k[X_1,..., X_d] $ (resp. $R^e :=k[Y_1,..., Y_e] $) be  polynomial rings in $d$ (resp. $e$) indeterminants over a field $k$ (maybe, it's ok if we more generally consider $k$ to be a Noetherian ring).
Let $I=\langle f_1,..., f_n \rangle $ be an ideal (generated by $f_i$'s) of $R^e \otimes_k R^f \cong k[X_1,..., X_e, Y_1,..., Y_f]$.
Consider the canonical inclusion $j:k[X_1,..., X_e] \to k[X_1,..., X_e, Y_1,..., Y_f]$ and the "contraction" of ideal $I^{c(e)}:= k[X_1,..., X_e] \cap I =j^{-1}(I)$.
Is there a well studied theory adressing the question & developing criteria when $I^{c(e)}$ "gives the original ideal $I$ back", ie when $I^{c(e)} \cdot k[X_1,..., X_e, Y_1,..., X_f]=I$?
Geometrically, this corresponds to scenario when for closed subscheme $V(I) \subset \Bbb A_k^{e+d}$ for canon projection $p_e: \Bbb A_k^e \times \Bbb A_k^d \to\Bbb A_k^e$ we get $V(I) =p_e^{-1}(p_e(V(I))$

What is $R^f$? $k[Y_1,\cdots,Y_f]$ presumably, but there are some typos so it's hard to tell -- e.g. $k[X_1,\cdots,X_e,Y_1,\cdots,\mathbf{X_f}]$.

Also, your question has an answer here; https://math.stackexchange.com/a/179071/98077, you are simply not using a field extension. Over a general Noetherian ring, I am not sure if the same answer goes through.

@walkar: sorry for not making it explicit. Indeed, $R^d $ I defined to be $ k[X_1,..., X_d]$ and sequent definition $R^f$ follows this "logic/pattern". Yes thanks, there some typos, will try to remedy them!

@walkar: I doubt that the answer given there adresses my problem: Firstly there the point of interest is if one can reconstruct the ideal living in the ring "down", the "smaller ring embedded in bigger here", there $k[x,y] \subset \overline{k}[x,y]$, in my case $R^e \subset R^{e+f}$, my object of interest is the reconstructibility of the ideal living in the ring "above".

Also, the central problem in my question the "lost of infomation" when we contract some indeterminants restricting $I$ from $R^{e+f}$ to $R^e$, so I think the discussion in linked thread adresses a rather different issue

I guess I was confused; I though the ideal $I$ started in $R^e$ -- in your question, $I$ starts in $R^{f+e}$?

@walkar: exactly

Clearly the ideal $I$ has the property you desire if and only if it is extended from $R^e$. What kind of condition are you looking for?

@Mohan: Yes, using your observation it suffice to develop techniques how to decide when a given ideal $I$ in $R^{e+f}$ comes from extension of an ideal from $R^e$. Are there some say "standard techniques" to approach this problem?
